# Simple subtraction gives wrong values in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following simple code:

```
a = tf.constant([7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4], dtype=tf.float32)

e = tf.constant(5.2, dtype = tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a - e))
```

the outcome of this subtraction is

```
[ 1.8000002   0.8000002   1.8000002  -1.1999998  -0.19999981 -1.1999998 ]
```

instead of

```
[ 1.8   0.8   1.8  -1.2  -0.2 -1.2 ]
```

that is very weird. What is possibly the problem?

Comment: You should look into [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). In short, this is not a problem with Tensorflow but with how numbers are stored in modern computers. Doing arithmetic often leads to rounding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple way the resaon is that 5.2 does not have a terminating binary representation. So, if you know how `1/3` looks in decimal, then just imagine the same situation in `5.2`. Always remember the following point :

> A decimal number will have a terminating binary representation if and
>   only if, the decimal written in its simplest fraction form, has a
>   denominator which is a power of `2`.

If you think of `5.2`, then it is `52/10` or `26/5`, and `5` is not a power of `2`. Now in float32 (double precision arithmetic), one has only 32 bits to represent it. So, of course, it ends up representing a number which is quite close to `5.2` but not quite exactly the same as it.

So, TensorFlow on computing the subtraction, gives you a slight difference.

If you however convert the numbers to `tf.float64` you will see the error getting disappeared, although the representation is still not exact. This is just a genuine effort of `Print` function making your life simpler. It is not showing you the full view. This is because in `64-bit` arithmetic, the difference between true value and internally represented value is much smaller than `32-bit` arithmetic. So, the `Print` function sees a continuous stream of zeros, which it truncates.

But if you use something like `Print('%.60f'% <YOUR  RESULT>)` you will see something like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...:     for i in range(10):
    ...:         c = sess.run(a - e)
    ...:     
2018-09-09 18:50:42.209402: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-09 18:50:42.209464: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-09 18:50:42.209475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:958]      0 
2018-09-09 18:50:42.209484: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N 
2018-09-09 18:50:42.209635: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10397 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)


for item in c:
    ...:     print('%.60f' % item)
    ...:     
1.780000000000000248689957516035065054893493652343750000000000
0.780000000000000248689957516035065054893493652343750000000000
1.780000000000000248689957516035065054893493652343750000000000
-1.219999999999999751310042483964934945106506347656250000000000
-0.219999999999999751310042483964934945106506347656250000000000
-1.219999999999999751310042483964934945106506347656250000000000
```